# I am in trouble while installing psycophy

Tags: installation, pip, psychopy

I am installing `psychopy` package using pip install and I am facing the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'preferences'

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
```

I've already installed `preferences` package and this error keep on showing up.

Comment: Suggest that this question would be better addressed on the PsychoPy user email list. It's not really a programming question.

Comment: Actually Otto, a new user support forum for PsychoPy has been set up at http://discourse.psychopy.org You could be one of the first customers there. The admins are keen to see how it works for new users.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem, and it seems like installing 'django-preferences' helped me

```
sudo pip install django-preferences
```

Hope this helps.